# create html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I need to create lines like this:

```
        <li data-target="c1.html"><span>I. </span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>
```

I really stumble with it, for example i can create `<li><span>` but when i try to add text to it then my span is gone.

It's probably quite easy but i can't get it done.
O yeah a lot of things can be done with a one-line solution. I don't care much about it being it compact, i prefer a clear solution (although one-line solutions can be clear).

here the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nCs99/1/

Comment: jsFiddle should only be used to demonstrate the code already within your question.  Please include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go:

http://jsfiddle.net/nCs99/3/

In your for loop I did like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < content.data.length; i++) {
    var item =  content.data[i];
    var ch = item.ch;
    var name = item.name;
    var target = item.target;

    // i need to create this:
    // <li><span>I. </span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>

    var li = $("<li>")
    var span = $('<span>');
    span.html("test");
    var span2 = $("<span>");
    span2.html(ch);
    li.append(span);
    li.append(span2);
    list.append(li);
}
```

Hope I got it right!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you mean but adding

```
list.append("<li><span>I. </span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>");
```

seems to work. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCs99/2/)
Just modify the string with the proper variables, like

```
list.append("<li><span>" + name + "</span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>");
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML with jQuery by using the .html() attribute. For example.

```
$('ul').html("<li class='myclass'><span>some stuff</span>My text here</li>");
```

**EDIT:**

Okay I might have misunderstood your question. This is good if you want to create the HTML using jQuery, which is what I think you might want to do. But by looking at your jsFiddle it looks like you just want to insert `<span>` tags into certain `<li>` tags. Anyways, I didn't use your jsFiddle, instead I recreated one with your mark-up and very basic examples of how you can do this with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/6XN5C/

Also here is the jQuery code. If you just want to insert spans into the `<li>` tags the `.prepend()` method would be a better option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // To insert into an existing tag
   $('.roman li').prepend('<span>I.</span>');

   //To Create a new tag inside of another
   $('#demo-ul').html("<li><span>I.</span>Het tijdperk der goden</<li>");

});
```

Comment: Sure, I created a fiddle using some of your code. And added an edit. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

So a simple solution here would be to break it up into parts.
Each time you make a statement it can return the newly created item.

Lets look at your example -

```
<li data-target="c1.html"><span>I. </span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>
```

We'll take a base object to start with - let us say for example the `<ul>` element that you are wanting to append to -

*This assumes a `<ul>` element like `<ul id="someList"></ul>` to be in the HTML markup.*

```
var myList = $("#someList");
```

And append to it another **new** `<li>` element returning it to a new object

```
var newElement = myList.append('<li data-target="c1.html"></li>');
```

Great! we got this far - now we add the `<span>`'s

```
var firstSpan = newElement.append('<span></span>').text('I. ');
var secondSpan = newElement.append('<span></span>').text('Het tijdperk der goden');
```

I've gone about this in a very spread out way - there is no need to perform each operation in a different command.  jQuery has a fantastic feature called `chaining`.

What chaining means (as the name imply's) is that you can chain functions together.  I already gave an example in the code above

```
var firstSpan = newElement.append('<span></span>').text('I. ')
```

As you can see I am appending the `<span>` element and immediately after calling the `text()` function.  This is possible because most if not all built-in jQuery functions (an indeed any well built plugins) will return the object itself when it exits.

For example -

```
var coldBeer = new Object();
coldBeer.drink = function(){
  // gulp...gulp...
  console.log('gulp...gulp...')
  return this;
}

coldBeer.refill = function(){
  // drunk...drunk...
  console.log('drunk...drunk...')
  return this;
}
```

Would allow us to do this -

```
coldBeer.drink().refill().drink().refill().drink();
```

because each function (* *hiccup* *) would return another cold beer!

### Cheers!

[image]
<sub>(source: [howthewestisfound.com](http://howthewestisfound.com/images/Misc/beer_pour.gif))</sub>

Comment: thanks, i tried it but it only adds 1 name, could u take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/nCs99/4/

Comment: You are going to have to update your post to include more information.  What exactly are you trying to do?  My post answers you original question - how to append an element. If you want to use recursion to populate a `<ul>` then this is not what you asked.  If you'll be more clear about what you want we'll be able to help you much more.   Jsfiddle is there to help out - don't rely only on it.  Place your code in your post and only use JsFiddle for reference.